# Possible to get individual numbers from list input from user

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently working on making a histogram from a set of numbers for homework. Making the histogram itself isn't the problem for me. However, the way my professor has a sample run posted of how the program should be made, it seems that when the prompt for the user to input integers for the histogram comes up, the input is done all in one line.

Example:

Input integers from 1 - 100 and let -1 terminate the sequence:

5 43 65 8 5 43 4 2 3 4 55 76 4 -1

So therefore, the program would have to go through each character one by one but also know whether a digit had an accompanying digit to make it a two-digit number and it would also have to know how to handle spaces. Normally, I would just write a program to display the prompt and then the user would type in each number and press enter, storing each value in an array until -1 was input.

So, my question is, is it possible for the program to scan a line of numbers correctly like in the example above? My guess is there would be some if statement that said if there was a character and not a space next then make it a double digit value but I don't know how I would go about doing that.

If this is possible, I would appreciate it if someone just led me down the right path of where to look.

Comment: Do you want to scan from user input, file or what?

Comment: User input. So the person would type out all the numbers they want separated by space only then end it with -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Scanner and sentinel value:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true){            
    int i = s.nextInt();
    if(i == -1) break;
    list.add(i);        
}
```

If you aren't allowed to use break, simply rewrite the condition to use the value of i;

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<intInteger
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = 0;
while(i != -1){            
    i = s.nextInt();
    if(i != -1) list.add(i);
}
```

Which results in one additional condition.

Comment: I will try this but unfortunately we aren't allowed to use breaks to get out of loops. Is there another way?

Comment: I'm getting these errors when testing: test5.java:7: unexpected type
found   : int
required: reference
List<int> list = new ArrayList<int>();
     ^
test5.java:7: unexpected type
found   : int
required: reference
List<int> list = new ArrayList<int>();
                               ^
test5.java:11: i is already defined in main(java.lang.String[])
        int i = s.nextInt();

Comment: @VB ouch.. sorry, you must use objects with List, therefore List<Integer>, plus there was a copy&paste error

Comment: Ok thank you. I hope I don't have any more questions.